# Create an ear flap

Tags: modeling, mesh, proportional-editing

I am trying to make the left ear flap in my model to match the following picture:
[image]

This is the baseline of the model:

[image]

When I try to rotate the ear it simply gets deformed:

[image]

And when I try rotating it with proportional editing, it is getting stretched and still doesn't look like in the picture:

[image]

Is there a better way to fold the ear so it would look like the flap in the picture?

Comment: You can add an armature (apply it later if you want) or also there is an armature option in Sculpt Mode.

Comment: Actually if you just learn some basic rigging (look for animated snake tutorial or something) you could add one or two bones in the ears and have a lot of control

Comment: @FFeller lol beat me to it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with the *Pose* brush in *Sculpt* mode:

[image]

[image]

But as FFeller says, it's probably better to use an armature so that you can come back to the default pose whenever you want (if you segment the bones it will be even rounder, and you can use an IK constraint to control the flexion more easily):

[image]